# Scroll multiple horizontal scrollview in sync when you scroll one in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

Below is a sample of what needs to be achieved in React Native:

> Title1
>
> Some description that spans horizontally using a ScrollView
>   (horizontal prop)...............................
>
> Title2
>
> Some description that spans horizontally using a ScrollView
>   (horizontal prop)...............................
>
> Title3
>
> Some description that spans horizontally using a ScrollView
>   (horizontal prop)...............................

The code for the same is:

> FlatList   --> View
>       --> Title + ScrollView (description)

Now, the expectation is when I scroll the description of one row, all the descriptions from the other row should scroll in sync.

Below is the structure:

```
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <ScrollView
      onMomentumScrollEnd={e => this.onScroll(e, index)}
      ref={node => { this.scrollRef[index] = node; }}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal
      style={styles.fundContainer}
    >
      <View style={styles.statsContainer}>
        <Text>Some Description</Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

And the method that I run on scroll:

```
  onScroll = (event: Object, index: number) => {
    this.scrollRef.forEach((scrollItem, scrollIndex) => {
      if (scrollIndex !== index) {
        scrollItem.scrollTo({
          x: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,
          y: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
          animated: true,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

I am using `onMomentumScrollEnd` which scrolls the item on scroll end. If I use `onScroll`, it creates a performance bottleneck and lags miserably.

Are there any workaround to scroll the list in sync?

Comment: Hey buddy, why don't you just create one big parent ScrollView, and place those title Views on the top of that parent ScrollView(using position absolute)? So you just need to scroll only one ScrollView horizontally, which will make it look like all the 3 scrollable sections are scrolling in sync, which is basically only one ScrollView scrolling horizontally!

Comment: 1. There is a list of items to be scrolled. We should use FlatList for a list which is also semantic.
2. I do not want all the list to scroll at once. The user should be able to scroll only one section at a time. Anyways,  I have resolved the issue months ago but I don't remember. probably, if I face it again I'll know